# Oracle Forms 10g running through forms builder fine but when from url runs its showed blank page

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

Hi dear I am running oracle form 10g form builder is working fine and runs forms from form builder but when I use the link to open fmx file its shows blank page on same system where forms builder running fine but when I want to try through copy link and run form then it shows nothing.

http://awsvm1-pc:8889/forms/frmservlet?config=hr

what I did `formsweb.cfg`

```
[hr] 
separateFrame=false
lookandfeel=oracle
userid=hr/hr@s
form=D:\application\test1.fmx
```

and `forms_path` also set in registry

```
C:\DevSuiteHome_1\cgenf61\admin;C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms;D:\application\*
```

and `default.env` also set the directory where application is placed

```
FORMS_PATH=C:\DevSuiteHome_1\forms,D:\application
```

what are my environment

1. OS Windows 7
2. Oracle Forms 10g
3. Using jre (verssion 6) not Jinitiator
4. Database 11g on redhate 6
5. Internet browser 8

What I feel is that when browser run it not load java plugins when runs through form builder than plugins are running
Best Regards #Littlefoot Please

Comment: perhaps you might try `config=applet`. Btw, do you mean `Internet explorer 8` for browser ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan yes internet explorer version 8 mean browser `config=applet` didn't work for me any other solution please

Comment: Did you mix the bit versions? I mean user Internet explorer 8 (32 bit) and install JRE (64 bit), you need on both the same bit version

Comment: @nightfox79 same bit version dear